# Generating unique usernames based on an existing username

Tags: gmail, username

I want to add a second Gmail account. It will have my name in it yet I don't need Google Apps as I don't need a domain and I don't need another Google Account. My name is very common so takes a while to add dots and numbers to get accepted.

Any URL I can use for instructions?

Also, I go into editing my current Gmail address to capitalize the first letter of name: `Katherine` and first letter of last name: `Evans` and I make corrections, click SAVE but it never corrects it.

Comment: GMail/Email addresses are case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your middle initial, you could pull off something like

- Katherine.F.Evans@gmail.com
- K.F.Evans@gmail.com.

You may have to use a nickname like

- Katy.F.Evans@gmail.com
- KT.F.Evans@gmail.com.

You get the idea.

The best website for checking availability is here:[New Gmail Account](https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?service=mail&continue=http://mail.google.com/mail/e-11-df57b2bee9775118b603dadfd6256-86cebf249fc87201280fda2fdeb1aa60cad2338e).

From this [article](http://mashable.com/2012/06/04/gmail-address-custom/), it says that it might be useful to use a website/service called [About.me](http://about.me). I have signed up for this service and it is excellent for displaying a personal or business bio in a [very professional way](http://about.me/davidmcgill/).

As far as needing to change the casing of your current email address, can you provide some additional details about where you are attempting to do this?